# Unable to complete the challenge --Create an approval process

Tags: trailhead

I am stuck with completing the challenge. I have no approval before but when I enter the name for  'initial submission action'  for a field update its give name error "Error: This Unique Name already exists or has been previously used. Please choose a different name" as shown in the image. I don't know how can I fix it. [image]enter image description here

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the "Unique Name" to something more unique - current unique name is already used somewhere in your org.

Examples:

- Account_Type_To_Pending_1
- Account_Type_To_Pending_1A
- Account_Type_To_Pending_challenge1